# NNET Multinomial Regression - Error in looping through multiple independent variables and extracting coefficients/std.errors

Tags: r, multinomial-logit, nnet

I have a scenario in which I'm using multinom (from NNET package) to perform multinomial regression over a set of 100+ genes (a given gene is an independent variable in each multinomial regression). I have the following setup for generating the models, which runs successfully.

```
formulas <- sapply(iv_list, function(x) as.formula(paste0("Outcome ~","`",x,"`","+ Covariate")))

models <- lapply(formulas, function(x){multinom(x, data = Data)})
```

My Q is how to extract the beta coefficient and standard errors for the set of 100+ genes

I tried the below...

```
summaries <- lapply(models,summary)
```

...it yields the following error:

Error in formula.character(object, env = baseenv()) :
invalid formula "CAPN9": not a call

CAPN9 being one of the gene names for which a multinomial model was fit

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
models <- lapply(formulas, function(x){multinom(x, data = Data, Hess = TRUE)})
```

When you don't ask for the Hessian matrix (to get sampling variance-covariance) it has to be produced when calling `summary`.  R is trying to reproduce the call and run the `multinom` model again to get the Hessian.  The formulas provided are not parsing right as they were passed through `lapply` (which records them as `x` if you look at each model's result object/list).  `nnet` is using that `x` formula to try to work backwards and re-run the model, but it is failing to parse right, which is causing the error.

All this is avoided by obtaining the Hessian up-front in the initial model call.